# Symfony3 - Downloading multiple files from a form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, symfony

I have a problem with getting multiple files at a time from my form. It looks like this:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /**/
        $builder->add('image', FileType::class, array('required' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'multiple' => true
            ),
        ));
        $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }
```

Here is it's controller.

```
 public function addProductAction(Request $request) {
    $create = new Products();
    $images = new Images();
    $form = $this->createForm(ProductsForm::class, $create);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $title = $form['title']->getData();
        $category = $form['category']->getData()->getId();
        $count = $form['count']->getData();
        $size = $form['size']->getData();
        $price = $form['price']->getData();
        $slug = $title;
        $image = $form['image']->getData();
        $brand = $form['brand']->getData();

        $zdjecia = $create->getImage();

        print_r($image);
    }
 }
```

The question now is: What do i have to add/change to to allow upload of those files and them adding them to the data base?

Comment: Paste your entities... see documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html)

Comment: Problem was that 'multiple' => true must be before 'attr' atribute ;)